# Perform an empty commit with mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, commit, mercurial-queue

With with Mercurial queues extension, I can make an empty commit with some commit message like so:

```
hg qnew patch_name -m "message"
```

Is there a way to do this without Mercurial queues? I tried simply:

```
hg commit -m "message"
```

but hg just says "nothing changed" and doesn't do the commit, and I don't see any "force" option that would override that.

If you're wondering about my motivation for doing this: we have testing infrastructure where you push to a special repository and it will trigger automated tests to run. You need to put a special string into the commit message of the tipmost commit that says which tests to run. Obviously, I don't want this string in there when I push to the actual repository. Rather than amending the commit twice (once to add the special string, and a second time to remove it), I would find it cleaner to just add an empty commit, and then roll it back -- and I can do this with mq, but I'd like to find a way to do it without mq.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `hg commit --amend` to create empty commits.

Just create an arbitrary commit and backout the change. Afterwards fold both commits together.

**Example:**

```
touch tmp                               # create dummy file
hg add tmp                              # add file and...
hg commit -m "tmp"                      # ... commit
hg rm tmp                               # remove the file again and ...
hg commit --amend -m "empty commit"     # ... commit
```

Comment: Similar to `hg commit --close-branch`, this will not create a truly empty commit — it will still leave a marker in the changeset and create an amend backup bundle. However, I think it's better in that it doesn't have the potentially confusing effect of marking a branch as closed when it's intended to remain open.

Comment: This won't work if you have already pushed to a remote repository

Comment: @matteo Why not? As long as you don't push in between the two `hg commit` commands you are fine.

Comment: That's what I said: if you have already pushed after the first commit you can't amend it.

Comment: Oh I see, I hadn't understood the example. I thought you were suggesting to use an ammend alone.

Comment: Ugly (should be in the interface), but it works. I needed this to mark the roleback point when I closed branch, on a linear set of commits, and had no real changes for now.

Comment: @richard agreed! But you can create an alias if you really need this more often by putting the following into your .hgrc file:
    `[alias]
    emptycommit = !touch tmp ; $HG add tmp ; $HG commit -m "<enter commit message>" ; $HG rm tmp ; $HG commit --amend "$@"`

Comment: Improvement of @JosefEisl alias `[alias] emptycommit = !touch tmp ; $HG add tmp ; $HG commit tmp -m "<enter commit message>" ; $HG rm tmp ; $HG commit tmp --amend "$@"` Commits should target our tmp file, so that we do not commit changes (so it is always an empty commit).

Answer (score 8):

In 2015 [a patch to the mercurial-devel mailing list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2015-May/069430.html) suggested adding an option to the commit command, called `--allow-empty` (much like [the similar git option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470029/how-to-commit-no-change-and-new-message)). However, [it was decided](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2015-May/069480.html) to go with a configuration option instead.

This ended up being [added in Mercurial 3.5](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_3.5_.282015-07-31.29) in 2015 July, by the name `ui.allowemptycommit`. One doesn't have to specify it in a user's or repo's configuration file however, it is sufficient to add a `--config` switch to a single command, like this:

```
hg ci -m "empty commit" --config ui.allowemptycommit=1
```

Additionally, [in 2020 it was suggested](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2020-July/142467.html) for the `hg rebase` extension command to consider the value of another, experimental configuration option. It is named `rewrite.empty-successor`, and can be set to either `skip` (the default) or `keep`. The configuration option itself was introduced with [Mercurial 5.5](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release5.5) in 2020 August, although I am not sure when the `rebase` extension started to consider it.

How it works seems to be that `rebase` [reads the new option](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/6.1/hgext/rebase.py#l206) and then [locally overrides](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/6.1/hgext/rebase.py#l555) the older `ui.allowemptycommit` option depending on whether `rewrite.empty-successor` is configured to `skip` or `keep`. The result is that the `rebase` extension of older Mercurial versions directly observes the `ui.allowemptycommit=1` option (version 4.8.2 tested), while the newer versions' extension observes `rewrite.empty-successor=keep` instead (version 6.1 tested). The newer versions ignore the external state of the `ui.allowemptycommit` configuration.

Therefore to get `hg rebase` to keep empty changesets somewhat portably, both options can be set so as to keep them, like in this example:

```
hg rebase --config rewrite.empty-successor=keep --config ui.allowemptycommit=1 ...
```

---

My use case for all of this is to use `hg convert` on an `svn` repo, then use an empty `hg commit` to become the initial commit (local changeset number 0). Then I will use `hg rebase` first to make the soon-to-be changeset 0 the parent of the first imported svn revision (so it will become local changeset number 1, matching the svn revision number), and second to fix a certain problematic commit that `hg convert` doesn't parse correctly. It is crucial to me that the `hg rebase` commands should keep empty commits, such as those based on `svn` revisions which only changed directories. (Directories are never tracked by Mercurial on their own, only files.)

Comment: If anyone is interested, [here is the finished script](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/svardos.scr/file/0824dc4cdd9d/upd.sh). I actually have to fix the broken changeset first, as it would interfere with the rebase onto my changeset 0. I reported the broken changeset created by `hg convert` [to the Mercurial bug tracker](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6667).

Answer (score 5):

You can make commit that's closing the branch:

```
hg commit --close-branch -m "message"
```

**Update:**

You can close branch once, but it can be reopened with another commit. Simplest way to reopen branch without changing files is to tag some revision. So you can use `hg commit --close-branch` for empty commit and then `hg tag` for reopening.

**Update v2**

Actually you can create new empty commits with just `hg tag` command. It has `-m` parameter for setting a commit message. If you don't really care about correctness of this tags, you can use just one tag name by calling `hg tag` with `-f` parameter:

```
hg tag t1 -f -m "message"
```

Comment: Won't these operations pollute the history with branch closing and tag creation events?

Comment: Closing the branch won't pollute history. It will just add new changeset. Tag creation adds new changeset with specific commit message, but you can override it with `-m` parameter.

Comment: Hey, you can actually just create new tags without closing the branch. If you don't care about tags but just a commit messages, you can even use just one tag and set it with `-f` flag. So, you can create empty commit with `hg tag t1 -f -m "message"`.

Comment: closing the branch or adding a tag is not a true *empty* commit.

Answer (score 5):

You can now create empty commits by just doing `hg ci -m "empty commit"`

e.g.

```
hg branch my-next-branch
hg ci -m "empty commit"
```

Will create a `my-next-branch` with a single empty commit that you can push to the remote repo.

Comment: I've always been able to have an "empty" commit that does nothing more than make a branch. Suppose that I have made seven commits to the branch and then want to just add a new commit message without file changes. Should `hg ci -m "empty commit"` work in that case? I tried it and it didn't work. I don't know if I just have an older version or if it's because this sample makes a branch first, which I'm not doing in the scenario I described.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that `hg graft . --force --edit` works fine for that purpose.

This will force-graft the current checked-out commit, so it'll be empty, and it'll open an editor to enter a commit message.