# What does `hg cp` do and how to "undo" it?

Tags: mercurial

I used Visual Studio Code (VSC) at work, and like usual, I view a file, such as

```
Foo.react.js
```

and use Save As

```
Bar.react.js
```

so as to create a new component file using `Foo.react.js` as a template.

However, when it got to CI/CD (Jenkins) and the push to production server stage, the file `Bar.react.js` had merge conflict with itself, which is strange, because why would a new file that only I created and edited conflict with itself?

Talking to the hg and CI/CD team, they told me that VSC (in my company) does an `hg cp` when we use Save As, and it treated Bar.react.js to follow the history of Foo.react.js.

So possibly somebody also modified Foo.react.js, and some lines in Bar.react.js conflicted with it.

I was also told that I can use `hg forget Bar.react.js` and then `hg add Bar.react.js` to fix the issue.

So the question is:

1. What exactly does `hg cp` do and why would it want to track history for a new file using an old file?
2. Is it true that I can only do `hg forget Bar.react.js` and then `hg add Bar.react.js` for the current commit and push, to fix the issue?  If I didn't use `hg forget` and `hg add` and then fixed that merge conflict and now all the files are finally in the repo, can `Foo.react.js` still conflict with `Bar.react.js` in the future?

The reason I think for (2), they may not conflict with each other in the future is that, if I do `hg forget` and `hg add` after all files are in the repo, then hg treats that as "nothing changed" and I cannot even commit.  If I `hg forget` and commit, and then `hg add` and commit again, and now I want to land and push this, the CI/CD would say that the `hg forget` commit does not pass the CI/CD tests (missing component), so I really wonder if I need to go through the `hg forget` and `hg add` because it seems nobody ever does that as nobody ever stated how it can be done once the files are all in the repo now.

So it becomes:
Now that all files are in the repo now, do I still need to do `hg forget Bar.react.js` and then `hg add Bar.react.js` so that these two files do not conflict with each other in the future.  If I need to do the `hg forget` and `hg add`, how should it be done?

Comment: As to 1 I think `hg cp` will remember where the file came from, the `hg forget` \ `hg add` cycle is probably intended to sever this connection. Also, there is a way to [get hg to do an empty commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541660/perform-an-empty-commit-with-mercurial/71428853#71428853) though I don't know with certainty that this will do what you want.

Comment: what a mess.  I don't know why `hg cp` existed in the first place: why in the world do we want two files with diff path and filenames compare with each other and create merge conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What exactly does hg cp do and why would it want to track history for a new file using an old file?

Tracking history of renamed files is very useful.

Say you been working on `button.jsx` for many years, and then it's renamed to `colorButton.jsx`. **Without** tracking history across renames, when looking at the history of colorButton.jsx, you would only see the history since it was renamed, as it would be considered a new file. Since button.jsx is no longer in the working directory, it might also be hard to know where the old history was.

copying / duplicating files is not as common, but I guess if you do want to duplicate the file, and maintain the common history it would be useful.

> 2. Is it true that I can only do hg forget Bar.react.js and then hg add Bar.react.js for the current commit and push, to fix the issue?

one can also break the association between the two files with:

`hg rename --forget colorButton.jsx`

Note:

one can read about this by typing

`hg help rename`

or

`hg help copy`

Comment: I think I found the answer: `hg cp` will follow the history for this ONE TIME. It is paranoid that there may be bug fix for that original file right at this moment. After the commit, hg will not follow the history any more. Reference: https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/daily.html#why-should-changes-follow-copies "Once your change history has a record that the copy and subsequent merge occurred, there's usually no further need to propagate changes from the original file to the copied file, and that's why Mercurial only propagates changes across copies at the first merge, and not afterwards."