# How to make a Mercurial commit with no files?

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for the Mercurial equivalent of `git commit --allow-empty` for testing purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force mercurial to accept an empty commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561608/how-can-i-force-mercurial-to-accept-an-empty-commit)

Comment: That thread deals with importing empty commits from SVN, which is not my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform an empty commit with mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541660/perform-an-empty-commit-with-mercurial)

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.  There doesn't have to be a change to a source file, but you have to have changes something, be it file permissions, branch name, tag, or something.

You say "for testing purposes".  If that's the case I usually just use

```
echo another line >> README ; hg commit -m 'added another line'
```

I can hit up-arrow enter on that plenty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution I've found is:

```
touch foo
hg add foo
hg commit -m 'Empty commit'
hg rm foo
hg commit --amend
```

Comment: This works beautifully --- thanks! (Although the fact that I have to do this in order to get an empty commit is kinda silly.)

Answer (score 0):

Works with MQ. Make a MQ changeset with some dummy change, then revert the change and refresh (`hg qref`) the patch. Voila.